# Check if a xml node contains sub child

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Is there a way to check if the node I am looking for, using `XPATH` does contain subnodes or not?

I have an xml file that a specific node sometimes has childs and some time it does not! How to check for this so I dont get too much NullReferenceExceptions !?

Check the example below:

```
var text = xml.SelectSingleNode("/Document/Tests/Test").InnerText;
```

If the current xml file I am working with does have the `Test` node inside `Tests` its working ok, but in another xml file the `Tests` node does not contain anything and it is just there for no apparent reason!?

Is there a command in XPATH to do this? something like!! :

`"/Document/Tests[NodeExist(Test)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/Document/Tests[Test]` will give you `Tests` nodes that only have a `Test` node as a child.

You can also run a selection against `/Document/Tests` and later call `element.GetElementsByTagName("Test").Count > 0` to make sure there is at least one `Test` node. This way you can programmatically show an empty string or an error message without the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can use the following xpath
"/Document/Tests[node()]"
This will give you all the Tests Nodes that have a child node. You can further improve to give the node name there as well as nodetype.

If you want specific nodes that have a child node called Test
use this
"/Document/Tests[Test]"

More examples you can find in MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A real quick Google gave this:

```
/Document/Tests/not(*)
```